# Limiting rotation to +20 to -20 degree

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Stepper motor should drive a frame to tilt, but not 360 degrees, but only within 20 to - 20 degree.
What simple machine elements do you use to restrict the freedom of movement?
It must be a mechanical solution, not a software one.
Can it be only done through gear elements and no further addition elements?

Something like the following
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7v2lVsjH4g

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a slot with a pin, the slot limits the distance the pin can move, then make sure the slot is machined to give +/- 20 degrees.

Comment: Can you give an image, video or link as example, is there a name I can search for these kind of freedom limiting elements? Maybe I should add it's for tilt&pan head for a camera for example. I want it to only tilt between +20 and -20 degree.

Really help appreciated for further own research, as I am totally not even unknowledgeable regarding machine elements and what sorts of stuff exist.

Comment: Search for “limit stops” as a start